# Setting LocalDateTime precision when using @CreationTimestamp/@UpdateTimestamp in hibernate (Spring-Data-JPA)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a bunch of failing test due to comparisons and a mismatch of precision between LocalDateTime and what MySQL support. The code is creating LocalDateTime within microsecond precision, where as MySQL only supports up to nanosecond precision.

I have an entity as such:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Table("my_table")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private LocalDateTime updated;
}
```

With corresponding table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

When I use my repository to save an Entity within a test, the test fails.

```
@Autowired
Repository<MyEntity, Id> aSpringDataRepository;

@Test
public void myTest() {

   // given
   MyEntity = new MyEntity();
   myEntity.setName("Foo Bar");

   // when
   aSpringDataRepository.save(myEntity);

   // then
   MyEntity myEntityFromDatabase = aSpringDataRepository.findById(myEntity.getId());
   assertThat(myEntity).isEqualTo(myEntityFromDatabase) //it fails here
}
```

With

```
myEntity.created == "2022-12-09T13:09:52.125720132"
myEntity.updated == "2022-12-09T13:09:52.125760760"
```

And

```
myEntityFromDatabase.created == "2022-12-09T13:09:52.125720"
myEntityFromDatabase.updated == "2022-12-09T13:09:52.125761"
```

I can see it's a precision issue. Unfortunately MySQL only supports nonasecond, so I can't change the schema. I could also update my test to be the following, but I think it's just a bit hacky.

```
@Autowired
Repository<MyEntity, Id> aSpringDataRepository;

@Test
public void myTest() {

   // given
   MyEntity = new MyEntity();
   myEntity.setName("Foo Bar");

   // when
   aSpringDataRepository.save(myEntity);

   // then
   MyEntity myEntityFromDatabase = aSpringDataRepository.findById(myEntity.getId());
   myEntity.setCreated(myEntityFromDatabase.getCreated());
   myEntity.setUpdated(myEntityFromDatabase.getUpdated());
   assertThat(myEntity).isEqualTo(myEntityFromDatabase) //now it passes

}
```

Is there a way, presumably via annotations, where I can force the precision of these values? Or is this just an irritating quirk I'm going to have to lump?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but you really shouldn't use all of these fields in equals and hashCode implementation, read this for explanation (https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/). And if you won't use these generated equals implementations, then you won't have problem with time precision in test cases.

Comment: @KamilBęben in this case, I think the test is good. OP checks whether what he saved in the DB can be retrieved the same as was saved. I came across this precision problem just now and am also wondering if there is a solution for this?